# Finding and replacing matched letters at same position

Tags: regex, string, bash, perl

It is a regex question, but I could not find a proper option for my case in Wiki page so I decided to ask here. May be a simple unknown option of regex can resolve my case.

I have a log file(a.txt) which has multiple lines of strings. I want to compare every two lines (1st vs. 2nd, 3rd vs. 4th...) and replace matched letter (not a string) to "."(or any special character).

a.txt:

```
1100110010
1100101100
0011001100
0110101111
.
.
.
```

result.txt:

```
.....1001.
.....01100
.0.10...00
.1.01...11
.
.
.
```

This may be XOR problem of two strings, so I tried this way, but it needed to be converted to ASCII and then XOR is doable (may be this approach is not right). I think there is a very simple way to do this job with SED/PERL. Any suggestion and/or guidance is appreciated. Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: What did you try for yourself? Post your research efforts

Comment: I don't think this could be anywhere near easy with `sed`. But perl ofcourse

Comment: Why is this as a "_regex question_"?  It is the last tool I'd use for this. Did you try to break each string into an array (of its characters) and iterate by index, comparing their characters? That is basic and simple to do, and it is predictable (it _will_ work out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer in sed.
It assumes that the lines are always equally long and only contain "0"s and "1"s.
Only "0"s or "1"s especially covers the assumption 'no ">" anywhere'.
It seems to be somewhat robust against differently long lines (I did a few simple tests), but no guarantee.

```
sed -En "N;s/^(.*)\n(.*)$/>\1\n>\2/;:a;s/>([01])(.*)\n(.*)>\1/.>\2\n\3.>/;ta;s/>([^$\n])/\1>/g;ta;s/>//g;p"
```

The code means:

- `-En` use extended regexes, do not print automatically
- `N`  look at this and next line at once
- `s///` do a single replace, non-globally because of the absence of `g`
- first replace introduces a cursor "`>`" at the start of both lines
- `:a` introduce a label for looping
- second replace does replace
  cursor, 0 or 1, rest of first line,
  start of second line, cursor, same 0 or 1
  by
  dot, cursor, rest of line one,
  start of second line, dot cursor
- then, in case of successful replace, loop to label
- otherwise third replace moves boths cursors one ahead and loops,
  except if end of line is reached
- fourth replace remoces the cursors
- `p` print result

Output for you sample input (interleaved with sample input):

```
1100110010
1100101100
.....1001.
.....0110.
0011001100
0110101111
.0.10...00
.1.01...11
```

The output differs in line two from your stated desired output, "." instead of "0",
but with all due respect, I think your desired output is incorrect there.

Using: GNU sed version 4.2.1

Answer (score 5):

Perl using [bitwise operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Bitwise-String-Operators):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

while ( !eof(DATA) ) {
    chomp( my $line1 = <DATA> );
    chomp( my $line2 = <DATA> );

    ( my $uniq_mask = $line1 ^ $line2 ) =~ s/[^\0]/\xFF/g;

    my $uniq1 = $line1;
    my $uniq2 = $line2;

    for ( $uniq1, $uniq2 ) {
        $_ &= $uniq_mask;
        s/\0/./g;
    }

    say for $line1, $line2, $uniq1, $uniq2, '';
}

__DATA__
1100110010
1100101100
0011001100
0110101111
```

Outputs:

```
1100110010
1100101100
.....1001.
.....0110.

0011001100
0110101111
.0.10...00
.1.01...11
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Perl version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# always use these two
use strict;
use warnings;

# handle errors in open and close
use autodie; # See http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html

while( ! eof( DATA ) ){
    chomp( my $line1 = <DATA> );
    chomp( my $line2 = <DATA> );

    my @data1 = split //, $line1;
    my @data2 = split //, $line2;

    # do the first
    for my $i ( 0 .. $#data1 ){
        if( $data1[$i] eq $data2[$i] ){
            print ".";
        }else{
            print $data1[$i];
        }
    }
    print "\n";

    # do the second
    for my $i ( 0 .. $#data2 ){
        if( $data1[$i] eq $data2[$i] ){
            print ".";
        }else{
            print $data2[$i];
        }
    }
    print "\n";

}

__DATA__
1100110010
1100101100
0011001100
0110101111
```

Comment: Or you can change both arrays during a single pass over the index, when needed -- `if ($d1[$i1] ne $d2[$i2]) { $d1[i1] = $d2[i2] = '.' }` (with `d` for `data`).

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned xor,

```
my $xor = $s1 ^ $s2;
my $mask = $xor =~ tr/\x01-\xFF/\xFF/r;
my $dots = $xor =~ tr/\x00\x01-\xFF/.\x00/r;

say $s1 & $mask | $dots;
say $s2 & $mask | $dots;
```

This code assumes the line feed has been removed, and it assumes the length of `$s1` and `$s2` are the same.